# Keras model.fit Buffered data was truncated in google colab during model training

Tags: google-colaboratory

When training a model using Keras.model.fit, I run into "Buffered data was truncated after reaching the output size limit." in the output, and the output does not update anymore.

```
Epoch 14/30
    51/721 [=>............................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.7874 - dense_6_loss: 0.4921 - dense_7_loss: 0.1440 - dense_8_loss: 0.1513 - dense_6_accuracy: 0.8556 - dense_7_accuracy: 0.9532 - dense_8_accuracy: 0.9511Buffered data was truncated after reaching the output size limit.
```

This seems to be some sort of memory error
[Buffered data was truncated after reaching the output size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463383/buffered-data-was-truncated-after-reaching-the-output-size-limit)

Even though the amount of text remains the same.

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I aslo have the same problem with `epochs=100` and `batch_size=1`. When I set the keras verbosity to 2 the issue was solved. For save the results of the learning as you got in `stdout` you can simply use a `logger` just like this:

```
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
csv_logger = CSVLogger(
        "log.csv",
        append=True,
        separator=','
    )
history = model.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=2,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
        callbacks=[csv_logger]
    )
```